# Google Drive: “Anonymous” access to not-yet shared file

Tags: google-drive, security, google-drive-sharing

I wanted to expand the case described in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45070/anonymous-animals-in-google-drive-for-not-yet-accessed-shared-file).

Probably the topic is more related to security, but I feel like I don't know enough about this, and probably someone might explain better and in simpler terms what's exactly going on.

As mentioned in the cited question, I also did some test in Google Drive. Create a new file, select the option of sharing a file with `Anyone with the link` *("Anyone who has the link can access.  No sign-in required.")*. Still no visitors. I didn't share the link, not open the link in new tabs, nor the file itself in another browsers. **Didn't do anything at all**.

At this point I started coping and pasting the link here and there: search bar on Google, random text file, random search bars. No sign of new visitors. But then I copied, **just copied**, the link in a text box of a Facebook chat I initiated with myself, and boom, got two new anonymous visitors on the file. Sent the message with the link, two more.

Who can explain me what's going on here? Do I have some security issues, or is some Facebook bot?

**EDIT 1:**
[Other relevant link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/6AQKgnRtXfU/iG1L-zWZeZMJ) that doesn't answer my question though.

Comment: Facebook tries to include a preview of the site when you post a link. It has to retrieve the page in order to do that. I don't see anything nefarious going on here.